# Feedback about joining a new Stack Exchange site (with suggestions)

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, new-users, site-name

**I'm not questioning the moderator decision; this is about the experience.**

I'm an experienced Stack Overflow user, but I just joined this [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange site today to ask a related question.

The experience was pretty bad, and I believe that is not what Stack Overflow wants, hence feedback and suggestions:

1. [My question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/172620/html-meta-viewport-fit-what-is-the-difference-between-auto-and-contain) was closed as "off topic" within 4 minutes. The reason given is... puzzling (at first glance):

[image]

2. OK, most likely I misunderstood what the "Web Applications" Stack Exchange site is. Let's try to understand... I clicked on "home", on the logo, a bit everywhere and there isn't any "about this Stack Exchange site". I couldn't find an "about" link to better understand what this Stack Exchange site is.
3. if the question is off-topic, but on-topic on another Stack Exchange site, could it be moved instead of closed?

So the suggestions would be:

1. make it much easier to find the description of a Stack Exchange sub-site, so that one can better understand what is on/off topic on the current Stack Exchange site. How about an "about" link close to (home)? or a "(?)"
2. when a question is closed as "off-topic", the automated message should point at the above description so that the author could better understand what is on/off topic
3. if there are frequent misunderstandings, they should be outlined during the "question writing" stage instead of waiting for an admin to mark it "off-topic" (maybe there was a popup, but I may have dismissed it due to [popup blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness))
4. Ideally, if the question is in the wrong Stack Exchange site, it should be moved in the correct one. That would be much more friendly! Or there should be an option for the author of the question to move it to another Stack Exchange site.

I hope this feedback helps! Please be nice!

Comment: "*How about an "about" link close to (home)? or a "(?)"*" the footer has some links https://i.stack.imgur.com/toh6J.png The header has a (?) https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmWam.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cO2Y.png

Comment: Can you please tell me how you arrived at [webapps.se]? Did you use the Stack Exchange Toolbar -> MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES? Did you see the hero header?

Comment: Related [Effectiveness of site name / descriptions of sites for "power users"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388388/289691)

Comment: "*when a question is closed as "off-topic", the automated message should point at the above description so that the author could better understand what is on/off topic*" there is a link in the header which brings you to the help centre. It's an article on closed questions which has lots of other links, including topicness. That's the first link in the first sentence on the first line of the article: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBCOc.png

Comment: "*if there are frequent misunderstandings, they should be outlined during the "question writing" stage instead of waiting for an admin to mark it "off topic"*"  moderators still have to abide by cause and effect. They can't really mark something as off-topic before you've written it. Nor can the system read and understand your question as you're writing it. There are links on the side when you're writing a question. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYLtk.png

Comment: From the tour of Web Applications I end-up on [their meta site](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/894/what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here-the-detailed-version)

Comment: For *"an experienced Stack Overflow user"* there's a lot of very basic SE functionality here being totally ignored. The help centre is linked in multiple places on every page, and every site has a topicality page that would have made entirely clear the question was off-topic before even asking it. There's only so much can be done for "new" users that ignore what is already there and plow ahead. You've surely seen it done on SO and got annoyed about it, why do it elsewhere and wonder?

Comment: Sometimes experience works against us. I get it myself as well, so allowing myself to reflect. Being here for so long, and having high rep on some sites, I thought I can do that on all SE sites, just to find out that in some, I just didn't get the scope correctly. Sometimes I learned from the mistakes and kept going, sometimes I realized that site isn't for me, but in all cases I did realize nothing was done against me, and each site just have its own scope, that isn't always trivial to understand, and it's fine.

Comment: as for #1, yes, I agree. what you can do is go upvote what you see in [`is:q [feature-request] easier to find help on-topic -[status-completed]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bfeature-request%5D+easier+to+find+help+on-topic+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D)

Comment: As an aside: feedback about how Stack Exchange network sites work in general is fine here; but feedback *specific* to your experience with an individual network site (for example: if you think the "off-topic" message in question should be rephrased, **after** having done your own research to understand the site's topic guidance of course) should go on that site's meta instead.

Comment: "if there are frequent misunderstandings, they should be outlined... maybe there was a popup but I may have dismissed it due to popup blindness" - in this case, *how else could it be done* that would meet your expectations?

Comment: The *Tour* page used to be called the *About* page. I can definitely see there is a discoverability problem. Most sites are also severely lacking a definition of what the site is about (not to speak of what is on-topic and off-topic), but not the one in question (though it somewhat hidden in the second paragraph): It links to the meta post *"[What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/894/)"*. Another notable exception is the [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) site.

Comment: I have added [tag:site-name] because the "feedback" and "suggestions" included mention that the site name is confusing, [tag:design] because there is a "suggestion" to improve the design / layout / UI, and [tag:association-bonus] because the OP mentions that they are an experienced user on another site, so they are not only a [tag:new-user] but a new user with the privileges of someone having +101 rep.

Answer (score 17):

TL;DR: most of what you're asking for already exists in some form. Some of it can possibly be improved, but a lot of it was right there in front of you and you seem to have made no use of it.

---

> 1. make it much easier to find the description of a stack exchange sub-site, so that one can better understand what is on/off topic on the current stack exchange. How about an "about" link close to (home)? or a "(?)"

As mentioned in the comments, **this already exists.** When I go on Web Applications, this is what I see:

[image]

Clicking the (?) icon opens a sub-menu that lets you take the tour and visit the help center, both of which will help you understand a site's on-topic guidelines.

[image]

> 2. when a question is closed as "off-topic", the automated message should point at the above description so that the author could better understand what is on/off topic

**It already does**, to an extent. Notice that the word "off-topic" is hyperlinked in the close-message: it takes you to [this help center page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), which further links to the site's on-topic requirements in the opening line.

> 3. if there are frequent misunderstandings, they should be outlined during the "question writing" stage instead of waiting for an admin to mark it "off topic"

Perhaps. The question editor does, again, link to the help center, but doesn't do a good job of explaining why you may want to read through it. Some extra description of what's in the help center, or a brief summary of some of the more common close reasons, *could* be useful to have there, but you'd still need to rely on people actually reading them.

> 4. Ideally if the question is in the wrong stack exchange, it should be moved in the correct one, that would be much more friendly! Or there should be an option for the author of the question to move it to another stack exchange.

I assume you already know this, but again, **this already exists**: it's called migration.

Your question was closed by a moderator, and moderators have the power to migrate questions anywhere on the network, so it's reasonable to question why they didn't migrate it. The answer to that is that, when a moderator migrates something, they have to be **absolutely certain** that the question will be on-topic on the target site, and won't be closed as a duplicate/low-quality/etc.

My assumption is that the moderator in question did not know of any Stack Exchange sites where your question would be well-received. The closest fit I can think of is Stack Overflow, and I'm not convinced it would be well-received there either.

Comment: Besides the Help (?) menu on the Stack Exchange toolbar, the page footer also includes a Web Applications section having the following links Tour, 
Help, 
Chat, 
Contact and 
Feedback. There is a feature request to about the Ask Question modal. It was declined for being "about five times longer than any other updated modal I could locate." :)

Answer (score 5):

I understand that the recent experience motivated you to make this post and that you have made it to help. First, thank you.

If you want to discuss your specific question, please post a question on Web Applications Meta or a message on the Web Applications main chatroom, Google Fu.

##### About the new user experience: Asking a Question

Remember that one of the *foundation stones* of Stack Exchange sites is the spirit of "search first". I mention this because the question posted on the referred main site and the question posted here look to be made without putting into practice this principle.

Related posts

- [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/289691) (2016)
- [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/289691) (2018)
- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691) (2020)
- [Introducing new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/289691) (2021)

##### Association Bonus and New Contributor: Regarding your context as a new user with experience

As an experienced user on another site, you have likely earned the [association-bonus](/questions/tagged/association-bonus). The screenshot doesn't show your user card on the site. It probably shows the "New contributor" label. It looks like your confidence about knowing the platform played against you. Another factor to consider is what your mood was at the time that you posted the question, i.e., if you were looking to post the question as fast as possible.

Over the years, there have been several related posts to the topic of this question in Meta Stack Exchange. Some might be hard to find due to the vocabulary used. One example is [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/289691). On this question, I have posted an answer, including snapshots showing the site header hero and other places where the site "purpose" and the links to related resources that match your suggestions:

- Header hero
- Ask Question modal
- Ask Question Draft guidance boxes
- Website footer

Also, it might be possible that you haven't paid attention to the tags, or their tag wikis were not helpful. Tag names might differ across Stack Exchange sites, but each community determines the tag usage. Also, each community might have different practices for handling tags, and each tag on each site has its own circumstances.

I think the challenge is dealing with [attentional control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attentional_control), [innatentional blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness), etc., trying to understand why users don't use / find stuff that is shown on screen. People with experience with UX and psychology will have a better way of explaining this.

Sometimes, it doesn't matter how much time and money is spent; there will always be someone who will not read, follow a link, or follow on-screen guidance. Sometimes, that someone could be anyone. Even the most experienced users might miss something in front of their noses.  Ideally, this will happen occasionally.

However, the user is responsible for what it does with the tool, no matter how friendly and nice it looks or not. Still, the feedback and suggestions are welcome.

##### Site Name

Some sites have cool names like Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault. The site from this post was derived originally, it was "graduated" as **Nothing To Install**, but a few moments after the official announcement of the site graduation, the site name was changed to Web Applications. IIRC, the announcement of this change occurred one day after the site graduation. A few years later, the site naming policies were standardized. See [Standardizing & Simplifying SE Site Names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207404/289691).

##### Move the question to the right site

Regarding the migration of the question, the Close dialog has some of the per-site Meta and three sites. In the case of Web Applications, the three sites are Stack Overflow, Super User and Webmasters.

Moderators also have a search box to migrate a question to any site. There is a chatroom for moderators where, among other things, we could ask if a question might be well received on another site.

Related

- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/289691) ([faq](/questions/tagged/faq)).

##### Conclusion

This post has several problems. Still, from several perspectives, I'm grateful for the time that you have taken to share your experience and your suggestions.

Remember that [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) has rules more strict than [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). Posts should be specific. They might be about broad concepts and experiences, but do not enter into too many details and don't include so many specific suggestions in a single post on a single site. Suggestions that will impact multiple sites are OK to share here. Look for at least two sites having the symptom. If you limit your post to a single experience, it might be more appropriate to post it on the per-site meta of the site where you have the experience to share.

If your intended audience is only Staff, use the Contact form instead of posting on Meta SE or a per-site Meta.

When posting a question on a new site, even if you have the [association-bonus](/questions/tagged/association-bonus), take the Ask Question guidance seriously: Follow the advice to ask good questions, as it was the first time you learned about it knowing that each site has its own culture and workings. This includes reviewing the help article about what is on-topic in the new site.

On the other hand, if what you are trying to say is that the Ask Question experience is convoluted, be direct and say that, but also say what you propose. Do not forget that Stack Overflow was launched in April 2008, Super User and Server Fault in 2009, and the others joined or were proposed as part of the Stack Exchange Network 2.0 starting in May 2010. There have been many changes since then, and more are on the way.